# Как с помощью Selenium спарсить класс html элемента

Tags: python, html, парсер, selenium

С помощью следующей строки кода я могу спарсить текст html элемента:

```
x=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]").text
```

Есть ли способ таким же образом получить класс элемента?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы спарсить класс используйте:

```
x= driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/header/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]").get_attribute('class')
```